# regex to extract nested elements

Tags: php, regex, nested

I have text document which contains following structure

```
{1,"StructEx",
[{1,"Element_1",[{2,"name","exampleName"},{3,"exampleValue",1},{2,"exampleComment","foo"}]},
[{1,"Element_2",[{2,"name","exampleName2"},{3,"exampleValue",2},{2,"exampleComment","bar"}]}]}
```

Where first value in parentheses is data type.
I need regex expression that will return (through couple of iterations)
all elements in StructEx so I can pack it in something like this

```
["StructEx"]=>
array(2) {
["Element_1"]=>
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "exampleName"
  ["exampleValue"]=>
  int(1)
  ["exampleComment"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}
["Element_2"]=>
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(12) "exampleName2"
  ["exampleValue"]=>
  int(2)
  ["exampleComment"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
}
```

Comment: Where is that data coming from? It looks like half-arsed json

Comment: A regex may not be the best way to do this: it'd probably be slower than a more proper parser. Can you use a quasi-JSON parser? Can you transform some chars and read it with python?

Comment: good..but show us your attempt!

Comment: pure regexp is not recursive. There are some extensions that are, but it's a real paint in the ass to use. Is changing your format to JSON an option?

Comment: Is this question really targeted at PHP or by what means are you planning to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming nesting is arbitrary deep, then the answer is **no, you cannot parse this kind of text document with regex.** If the depth is finite, it's painful, but doable.

### Why the heck is that?

#### Alphabets

To answer your question in more details, let's introduce some awesome dry theory.

Let's define an alphabet Σ as an non-empty set of symbols (a more technically correct definition would come from category theory by treating an alphabet as a non-empty free object, but for the sake of the argument this definition will suffice.

In our alphabet Σ, we can define a set of all finite strings (read: words) over the alphabet, that is:

> Σ = {s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub>, ... ,s<sub>n</sub>}
>
> Σ* = {ε} ∪ {s<sub>i1</sub>s<sub>i2</sub>...s<sub>im</sub> | s<sub>ik</sub> ∈ Σ, m > 0, 1 ≤ k ≤ n}, where ε is an empty string

As an example, it means that if we have an alphabet `Σ = {a, b, c}` and some of the words in Σ* will be `aaaaaa`, `abababa`, but not `abd`, because we don't even know that `d` exists.

#### Regular expressions & languages

Given the alphabet Σ, we have regular expressions like `ab*|c`. I'm skipping formal definition of regex to make it less confusing, so let's assume it's our plain old "practical" regex.

Each regular expression defines defines a regular language, e.g. in this example the language consists of words `a`, `ab`, `c`, `abbbbbc`, but not `abc`.

#### Finite automata

Each regular language can be expressed as a [finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), a device that can recognize regular expressions. For the aforementioned regular expression `ab*|c`, an automaton looks like this:

[image: ab*|c]

0 is a *start state*, double circles are *accept states*. In short, the automaton starts in state 0 consumes each letter of a word and moves according to the transition arrows. If it ends up in the accept state, we say it *accepts* the string. Otherwise, we say it *rejects* it.

So in this case, feeding a string `abb` into our machine:

1. Start in state 0
2. Consume `a`, move to state 1
3. Consume `b`, move to state 3
4. Consume `b`, move to state 3
5. String is empty and state 3 is an accept state, so this machine accepts the string or, equivalently, our regex pattern matches the string.

Let's see what happens when we feed `abc` into our machine:

1. Start in state 0
2. Consume `a`, move to state 1
3. Consume `b`, move to state 3
4. Consume `c`, nowhere to move, string is rejected

So our regex does not match `abc`. All of this is basically the same as practical regex with some added theory.

#### Equivalence

There is a theorem that states that *each regular language is finite automata-recognizable.* That means, if there exists a regular language (and an underlying regular expression) that can match your desired pattern, there should be an equivalent finite automaton.

#### So, why not?

But the nesting in your pattern has infinite depth. Therefore, you will need an *infinitely* large finite automaton that is equivalent to the regular language, which is contradictory to the definition of a *finite* automaton.

#### Reference

1. [Regex & Automata](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ebmk/se211lectures/lecture14.pdf)

#### Disclaimer

As you can see, I skipped inductive definition of regex, finite automaton from category theory perspective, closures under operations, and some other formal stuff. You are welcome to read about it in the aforementioned reference links.